# white-space: nowrap breaks flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox, whitespace

I have created a responsive layout for an app using Flexbox.
The layout calls for a collapsible menu on the left, a block with a header and body in the middle and a toggleable help-pane on the right (there's more to it but that's the basic structure).

The left menu has two states: 180px wide or 80 px wide. The help pane is either hidden, or takes 180px. The middle box takes the rest of the space. Flexbox works like a charm.

The trouble starts when I make a scrolling div using `white-space: nowrap`. I have a bunch of items that need to be displayed in a horizontal scroller, so I have a list div with the items, set to `overflow:auto` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Usually this works like a charm, but now it breaks my flex layout. Instead of taking the width of the parent (flex) div, the scroller makes the div wider, which in turn pushes the help-pane out of bounds.

---

The following fiddle illustrates this issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/PieBie/6y291fud/

You can toggle the help-pane by clicking *toggle help* in the menu bar. **Recreate the issue by clicking *list whitespace toggle* in the menu, this toggles the `white-space: no-wrap` CSS property of the list. If the help-pane is open, you can see it gets pushed out of bounds.**

The bottom list is what I want to achieve, but I want it to be full width of its parent.

I can recreate the issue in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Vivaldi and Edge. Internet Explorer 11 plays nice (°_°). I would prefer a pure CSS solution (SCSS is also an option), but if need be I can use JS.

---

```js
$('#nav-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
$('#help-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $('#help-pane').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('#list-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $('#list').toggleClass('nowrap');
});
```

```css
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}

#body{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#abc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#shell{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

  #left{
    flex: 0 0 180px;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 0;
    background:lightblue;
  }
  #left.collapsed{
    flex: 0 0 80px;
  }
  
  #mid{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    align-items:stretch;
    align-content:stretch;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    min-width: 0;
    background:purple;
  }
      #mid-top{
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        min-height:100px;
        background:green;
      }
      #mid-bottom{
        min-height:calc(100% - 100px);
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        background:lightgreen;
      }
      #list{
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      #list.nowrap{
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      #secondlist{
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 250px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .list-item{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 2px;
        background: purple;
      }
      .list-item.odd{
        background: violet;
      }
      
#help-pane{
  display:none;
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  background:red;
}
#help-pane.visible{
  display:inherit;
  flex:0 0 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
 <div id="shell">
      <div id="left">
          <div id="nav">
            - menu -
          </div>
          <div id="help-toggle">
            help toggle
          </div>
          <div id="nav-toggle">
            nav toggle
          </div>
          <div id="list-toggle">
            list whitespace toggle
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mid">
          <div id="mid-top">
                - mid top -
          </div>
          <div id="mid-bottom">
               - mid bottom- <br><br>
               <div id="list">
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
               </div>
               <hr>
               <div id="secondlist">
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div id="help-pane" class="visible">
   - help-pane -
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The most efficient solution as for now is using `-webkit-line-clamp`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

You can specify number of lines to preserve, for example 1.

Old solution based on `min-width: 0` does not work on complex layouts with wide usage of `flex`.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

This is caused by the [default flex-box behaviour](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto), which prevents flex-boxes of becoming smaller than it's contents.

The solution to this issue is setting `min-width: 0` (or min-height: 0 for columns) to all parent flex-boxes.
In this specific case (and in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PieBie/6y291fud/)):

```
#shell{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width: 0; /* this one right here does it!*/
}
```

---

```js
$('#nav-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
$('#help-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $('#help-pane').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('#list-toggle').on('click',function(){
 $('#list').toggleClass('nowrap');
});
```

```css
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}

#body{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#abc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#shell{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

  #left{
    flex: 0 0 180px;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 0;
    background:lightblue;
  }
  #left.collapsed{
    flex: 0 0 80px;
  }
  
  #mid{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    align-items:stretch;
    align-content:stretch;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    min-width: 0;
    background:purple;
  }
      #mid-top{
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        min-height:100px;
        background:green;
      }
      #mid-bottom{
        min-height:calc(100% - 100px);
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        background:lightgreen;
      }
      #list{
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      #list.nowrap{
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      #secondlist{
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 250px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .list-item{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 2px;
        background: purple;
      }
      .list-item.odd{
        background: violet;
      }
      
#help-pane{
  display:none;
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  background:red;
}
#help-pane.visible{
  display:inherit;
  flex:0 0 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
 <div id="shell">
      <div id="left">
          <div id="nav">
            - menu -
          </div>
          <div id="help-toggle">
            help toggle
          </div>
          <div id="nav-toggle">
            nav toggle
          </div>
          <div id="list-toggle">
            list whitespace toggle
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mid">
          <div id="mid-top">
                - mid top -
          </div>
          <div id="mid-bottom">
               - mid bottom- <br><br>
               <div id="list">
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
               </div>
               <hr>
               <div id="secondlist">
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item">&nbsp;</div>
                 <div class="list-item odd">&nbsp;</div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div id="help-pane" class="visible">
   - help-pane -
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c08hey1a/

Comment: @SteveCahn: it is the default as defined in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto).

Comment: it works but how you make the min width working if you set 0

Comment: @luky: You just need to set a value for min-width so it doesn't default to 'box content'. So you can set it to whatever value you like.

Comment: It may be worth highlighting the phrase "to all parent flex-boxes" and pointing a big arrow at "all". If your flexbox container is nested within other flexbox parents, each will need the `min-width:0` style applied.

Comment: Part 1: This isn't really a flexbox issue, it's more that nowrap content sets the minimum width to the unwrapped content which is why it's really long and causes overflow. For a non-flexbox example let's say you have a container div and it's child has the nowrap content. Intuitively you'd think setting container div's `width: 100%` will fix issue because it will set width same as parent element. But that won't work because the minimum width of the container div is now set to nowrap child content. That's why setting `min-width: 0` to container div fixes it.

Comment: Part 2: I guess the take away with percentage value widths such as `width: 80%` means that take 80% of parent's width as long as minimum width content allows it.

Comment: The most efficient solution as for now is using `-webkit-line-clamp`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

You can specify number of lines to preserve, for example 1.

Old solution based on `min-width: 0` does not work on complex layouts with wide usage of `flex`.